# Start a new pod when a livenessProbe fails

Tags: kubernetes

I have Kubernetes pods that run multiple containers. One of these containers runs `nginx`. The `nginx` container has a `livenessProbe` that checks whether the service works. When this probe fails, it means that one of the containers failed.

```
  containers:
    - name: someservice
      ....
    - name: someotherservice
      ....
    - name: nginx
      ....
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /check-all-services-in-pod
          port: 80
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 5
        timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Now Kubernetes would restart the `nginx` container, because the probe was defined on that container. But the problem likely is that one of the other containers stopped working. It's just difficult to define probes on those containers. So I'd like the whole pod to be scrapped when the `livenessProbe` on the `nginx` container fails. And a new pod to be created as replacement.

I've read about `restartPolicy: never`. Which would cause the container to go into a failed state. Will this cause Kubernetes to remove the pod, and start a new one?

Comment: Can you split this into multiple Deployments?  Then you can attach the liveness probe to the specific component that needs to be restarted, and not the Nginx proxy which is working fine.

Comment: @DavidMaze Well I could split it into separate deployments. But those other containers are hard to check for liveness. So I wanted to rely on an endpoint in the nginx container that also checks those services.

Answer (score 0):

If the liveness probe is failed and the restartPolicy is set as never then the kubernetes will not restart the container for any reasons like failed liveness probe.

So you need to use restartPolicy: Always or restartPolicy: On failure where the kubernetes will restart the container if they stop or fail , this will ensure the container restarts continuously. You can find more information about restart policy in this [blog](https://gaurav-kaushikgk88.medium.com/self-healing-pods-in-kubernetes-their-restart-policies-84d929778e6d) authored by Gaurav.

```
spec:
  restartPolicy: Always
  containers:
    - name: someservice
      # ...
    - name: someotherservice
      # ...
    - name: nginx
      # ...
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /health
          port: 80
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 5
```

As per this [official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#when-should-you-use-a-liveness-probe:%7E:text=If%20you%27d%20like%20your%20container%20to%20be%20killed%20and%20restarted%20if%20a%20probe%20fails%2C%20then%20specify%20a%20liveness%20probe%2C%20and%20specify%20a%20restartPolicy%20of%20Always%20or%20OnFailure.):

If you'd like your container to be killed and restarted if a probe fails, then specify a liveness probe, and specify a restartPolicy of Always or OnFailure.

**Below scenarios will play an important role in restarting the container:**

1. Reduce the [failureThreshold](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes) as the default is 3 times so the kubernetes will wait for probes to fail 3 times then the container is restarted.
2. Check [terminationGracePeriodSeconds](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) period parameters by default it is 30 sec which will help in termination of pods.

Comment: Check my previous [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74716367) for more additional information.

Comment: The thing is that the failure may be in one of the other containers, and I want the whole pod scrapped, not just the nginx container restarted.